# Accumulation Updater for Cryptography

Tags: interactive-proofs

I want update in place for sorted element list and proof for accumulator encoding of only element updated. I try to find technique similar to this, but only GCTI pop up and similar methods.

It must get elements in order of sorted list, replace ith element ($e^i$) with update list element ($e'^i$) to make new accumulation with modification. I must need proof so accumulation with update and replaced element is accepted and non-update elements check to be not updated.

If anyone know method similar to this one or some place I can find, I greatly appreciate.

Comment: I’m not certain if I fully understand your question, but it sounds like [cryptocounters](https://books.google.dk/books?id=wH38RuILlCoC&pg=PA104&lpg=PA104&dq=cryptocounter&source=bl&ots=FoXqtAEDaJ&sig=ACfU3U3V4dWxHNvlxnGQbx2SAX19ODSrcg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAqITs3OT7AhVHQvEDHRGaBh8Q6AF6BAgEEAM#v=onepage&q=cryptocounter&f=false) as described in chapter 5 of Malicious Cryptography by Young and Yung might be the idea that you are looking for.

Comment: Could you please indicate if the solution proposed by @DanielS is in the direction that you are looking for and why this is the case?

Comment: [Malicious Cryptography by Young and Yung](https://doc.lagout.org/Others/Malicious%20Cryptography%20-%20Exposing%20Cryptovirology.pdf) I think direction of Daniel is similar, but I must expand to meet requirement. This is good start, thank you